# Creating a set-like mapped attribute in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, set

I've done some reading and Googling, but am still not sure if there is a native / built-in way to create a mapped attribute in an SQLAlchemy object, that creates a set-like attribute for a similar scheme:

```
User                             UserTag
+----+-----------------+         +---------+-----------+
| id | email           |         | user_id | tag       |
+----+-----------------+         +---------+-----------+
| 1  | foo@example.com |         | 1       | footag    |
| 2  | bar@example.com |         | 1       | something |     
+----+-----------------+         | 1       | tagbar    |
                                 | 2       | something |
                                 | 2       | 3rdtag    |
                                 +---------+-----------+
```

So that each User object has a User.tags mapped attribute, which is (or behaves like) a set of strings - e.g. the following would work:

```
>>> user = session.query(User).filter(User.id == 1).one()
>>> print user.tags
set(['tagbar', 'something', 'footag'])
```

Comment: What specifically about a set do you need?  Uniqueness?  O(1) lookup?

Comment: Well, both, although to be honest the lookup time is not critical as I don't expect the number of mapped values to be large; Each user can have up to 10 or so tags, and mostly I want to know if `'tagbar' in user.tags`. 

The mapped table has a unique key defined on (user_id, tag) so uniqueness is guaranteed in the DB level. It just makes sense to me to have a set or set-like data structure for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Association Proxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) to achieve this:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    tags = relationship('UserTag', collection_class=set,
                        cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")
    tagset = association_proxy(
        'tags', 'tag_name',
        creator=lambda tag_name: UserTag(tag_name=tag_name),
    )

class UserTag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_tags'
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    tag_name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

Then you can work with the model in a manner:

```
# create sample data
foo = User(
    email='foo@example.com',
    tagset={'footag', 'something', 'tagbar'}
)
bar = User(
    email='bar@example.com',
    tagset={'something', '3rdtag'}
)
session.add(foo)
session.add(bar)
session.commit()

bar = session.query(User).get(2)
assert 'something' in bar.tagset
bar.tagset.remove('something')
assert 'something' not in bar.tagset
```

Also adding a `UserTag` with the same `tag_name` value will be handled properly.